# Voting to reopen a site proposal on Area 51

Tags: support, area-51

I recently went searching to see if there was a Stack Exchange site about relationships and found [a proposal for Relationships and Dating](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44577/relationships-and-dating). Unfortunately, I have no way of pledging my support, as it was closed three years ago.

Is there a way to vote for a site to be reopened? I'd love to pledge my support and help give good site ideas a second chance.

Comment: You can always re-suggest it but in this case, it's already been done: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/104423/relationships

Comment: There is already a ton of info about this. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=reopen+%5Barea51%5D and https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=reopen for starters. Generally, you just create a new proposal, trying to do better the second time around. Also, [Area51 meta](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/) is the place to ask this.